# Show html dropdown list according chosen options

Tags: python, html, sql, cgi

I'm building an small web app querying a database with python CGI. The logic is:
HTML Form - Python CGI - SQL query - python cgi prints results.

At the moment it works, but now I'm stuck creating the forms. What I want to do is auto fill the second form according the results of the first one. Example:

First Dropdown one options: Car, Motorcycle, BUS, Train.
Second dropdown: If I chose car, sow only car options. If train, only train options...

I know how to make it with `SQL ('WHERE type = 'car'')` But I don't know how to fill the html form.

I'm not using any framework, just HTML, Python (instead of php) and Postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ajax: when the first select changes, you have to pass the selected value to the remote python script that processes the request and returns the result to the page: at this point via javascript must populate the second select.
The data can be simple html or json formatted.
This is an example using jquery and ajax (remember to include [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)) :
html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select class="changeStatus" name="changeStatus">
            <option value="0">Car</option>
            <option value="1">Motorcycle</option>
            <option value="2">BUS</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
//  change event handler
$('select.changeStatus').change(function(){
    // You can access the value of your select field using the .val() method
    //alert('Select field value has changed to' + $('select.changeStatus').val());
    // You can perform an ajax request using the .ajax() method
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'your_script_python.py', // This is the url that will be requested

          // select value available inside your_script_python.py
          data: {selectFieldValue: $('select.changeStatus').val()},

          // on success: populate your second select.
          success: function(html){ 
            alert('data passed: ' + html);
           },
          dataType: 'html' // or json 
    });

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I knew there was something more 'beyond' SQL, HTML and Python. I'm quite newbie programmer, and I have not any experience in Ajax, but, for now, I know what tutorials do I need to read. Thanks for the example!